# write a script to send files to box application by automatic developer token generation

Tags: python, sdk, box-api, box, boxapiv2

Requirement: I need a script that sends files to box.

So far, i managed to send the files to box by following https://docs.box.com/docs/getting-started-box-integration . I am using box-python-sdk to acheive this, but i have to use this developer token which is active only for 60 min for authenticaton. I have to generate a developer token everyday to run this script.

```
    oauth = OAuth2(
         client_id=CLIENT_ID,
         client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
         access_token=DEVELOPER_TOKEN,
         ) 
client = Client(oauth)
```

I cannot set the redirect URI as am not running an application on a server, am just running this script using "python box.py ". Is there a way to refresh the developer token in my script?

Comment: @nucleo  i tag you since you have answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609327/box-com-api-oauth-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using JWT authentication, refer https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk.